# Convert BSON ISODate to NumberLong in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, date, timestamp, type-conversion, bson

I have a collection in MongoDB that has `created` fields with values currently stored as a BSON ISODate object. I want to convert all of those to NumberLong objects containing a timestamp.

First I tried this (in Mongo shell):

```
db.collection.find( { "created" : { "$type" : 9 } } ).forEach( function (x) {   
  x.created = new NumberLong(x.created);
  db.collection.save(x);
});

JavaScript execution failed: Error: could not convert "Tue Mar 18 2014 18:11:21 GMT-0400 (EDT)" to NumberLong
```

Apparently a date string cannot be cast as a long...fair enough. Then I tried this, thinking I could make use of the Javascript Date object's UTC method:

```
db.collection.find( { "created" : { "$type" : 9 } } ).forEach( function (x) {
  x.created = new Date(x.created).UTC();
  db.collection.save(x);
});

JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Object Tue Mar 18 2014 18:11:21 GMT-0400 (EDT) has no method 'UTC'
```

I've tried several other variations, but nothing has worked yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the underlying numeric value of the `Date`, you can call [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) on it:

```js
x.created = new NumberLong(x.created.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

The ISODate object has a "valueOf" method that will return an epoch time. Here is an example generating this via mongo shell:

```
replset:PRIMARY> var date = ISODate()
replset:PRIMARY> date
ISODate("2014-06-25T16:31:46.994Z")
replset:PRIMARY> date.valueOf()
1403713906994
replset:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. JohnnyHK beat you to it, but your answer is also very helpful. Cheers!